# Иньекция dll в программу, работает на 32 bit, не работает на 64 bit

Tags: dll, hook, x86-64, x86

Есть функция, которая выполняет иньекцию длл (32 bit) в процесс (также 32bit). если собираю свою программу (инжектор) как 32 bit - все прекрасно работает. если как 64 bit - иньекция не производиться (хотя функция возвращает результат 2 (то есть успешный)

```
uint32_t CreateRemoteThreadUNM( LPCSTR DllPath, HANDLE hProcess )
{
    uint32_t result = 0;
 
 
 
    LPVOID LoadLibAddr = reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA"));
 
//    LPVOID LoadLibAddr = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress( GetModuleHandleA( "kernel32.dll" ), "LoadLibraryW" );
 
    if( !LoadLibAddr )
        return result;
 
    LPVOID pDllPath = VirtualAllocEx( hProcess, nullptr, std::strlen(DllPath), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE );
 
    if( !pDllPath )
        return result;
 
    BOOL Written = WriteProcessMemory( hProcess, pDllPath, (LPVOID)DllPath, strlen(DllPath), NULL );
 
    if( !Written )
        return result;
 
    HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread( hProcess, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibAddr, pDllPath, 0, NULL );
 
    if( !hThread )
        return result;
 
    result++;
    WaitForSingleObject( hThread, INFINITE );
 
    if( !VirtualFreeEx( hProcess, pDllPath, 0, MEM_RELEASE ) )
        result++;
 
    CloseHandle( hThread );
    return result;
}
```